# Is va_end required after a vsnprintf_s call?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz.aspx) shows this sample code snippet for `vsnprintf_s`:

> ```
> // crt_vsnprintf_s.cpp
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <wtypes.h>
>
> void FormatOutput(LPCSTR formatstring, ...) 
> {
>    int nSize = 0;
>    char buff[10];
>    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
>    va_list args;
>    va_start(args, formatstring);
>    nSize = vsnprintf_s( buff, _countof(buff), _TRUNCATE, formatstring, args);
>    printf("nSize: %d, buff: %s\n", nSize, buff);
> }
>
> int main() {
>    FormatOutput("%s %s", "Hi", "there");
>    FormatOutput("%s %s", "Hi", "there!");
>    FormatOutput("%s %s", "Hi", "there!!");
> }
> ```

In this sample, `va_start` is called *without* a matching `va_end`.

Is this a doc bug in MSDN, or should we just call `va_start` *before* invoking `vsnprintf_s` and then let this function do the cleanup (i.e. calling `va_end`) for us?

BTW: I tried the above code and it works with VS2015 with Update 3, but I don't know if it's just undefined behavior...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`va_end` needs to be called for every `va_start`. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_end:

> If there is no corresponding call to `va_start` or `va_copy`, or if `va_end` is not called before a function that calls `va_start` or `va_copy` returns, the behavior is undefined.

Not only do you need `va_end` but you also need to make sure that your function does not return before `va_end` is executed if `va_start` or `va_copy` is executed.

To answer your question - yes, this is a documentation bug in MSDN.

Comment: I looked today in the MSDN, the bug is now eliminated.  `va_end` is now included at the end.

Answer (score 3):

From [the MSDN page for `va_arg`, `va_copy`, `va_end`, `va_start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx):

> After all arguments have been retrieved, `va_end` resets the pointer to
>   NULL. **`va_end` must be called on each argument list that's initialized
>   with `va_start` or `va_copy` before the function returns**.

So yes, this is a documentation bug.

Comment: A documentation bug that slipped through because the MS implementation of `va_end` doesn't do all that much, and omitting it is "harmless".  `va_end` exists because some platforms (not x86) need it to avoid completely trashing the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `vsnprintf_s` is supposed to be similar to `vsnprintf`, then you shouldn't expect it to invoke `va_end()` for you:

> The functions `vprintf()`, `vfprintf()`, `vdprintf()`, `vsprintf()`, `vsnprintf()` are equivalent to the functions `printf()`, `fprintf()`, `dprintf()`, `sprintf()`, `snprintf()`, respectively, except  that  they  are  called  with  a
>          `va_list` instead of a variable number of arguments.  **These functions do not call the `va_end` macro.**  Because they invoke the `va_arg` macro, the value of `ap` is undefined after the call.  See `stdarg(3)`.

(my emphasis)